# the desired result is not appropriate in Vba array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I want to do sum total or equal to sumif but the result doesn't match below code. The result should be in the "RECON" sheet in column B not in column G and below I attach a screenshot of the desired result and I want to only add or modify a little without changing the structure of the code below.
Thanks
roy

```
  Sub test2()
  Dim dic As Object
  Dim shs As Variant
  Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, c As Variant, d As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, lr As Long, lt As Long, m As Long, n As Long
  Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  shs = Array("TEST", "A")
  For i = 0 To UBound(shs) Step 2
    lr = Sheets(shs(i)).Range(shs(i + 1) & Rows.Count).End(3).Row
    lt = lt + lr
    If i = 0 Then a = Sheets(shs(i)).Range("A2:G" & lr).Value
  Next
  ReDim d(1 To lt, 1 To 7)
  'TEST
  For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
    If Not dic.exists(a(i, 1)) Then
      n = n + 1
      dic(a(i, 1)) = n
      d(n, 1) = a(i, 1)
    End If
    j = dic(a(i, 1))
    For k = 7 To 7
      d(j, k) = d(j, k) + a(i, k)
    Next
  Next
  Sheets("RECON").Range("A3").Resize(n, UBound(d, 2)).Value = d
End Sub
```

[image: Wrong Result]
[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Your code is overcomplicated without any reason. `shs = Array("TEST", "A")` part works but only complicates the code readability. Then, try using `ReDim d(1 To lt, 1 To 2)`. Instead of useless loop starting from `For k = 7 To 7`, try simple using `d(j, 2) = d(j, 2) + a(i, 7)`.

Comment: @FaneDuru ,`shs = Array("TEST", "A")` 
because I want to use it for multi sheets and your code works as I want and please make it your answer

Comment: Using it for more sheets, makes sense. I thought you found the code somewhere, processing more sheets and adapted it for only one, instead of simple writing two code lines. Glad I could help.  I should post an answer trying to simplify the code, only if I could see the range to be processed and I could better understand what you try accomplishing. In such circumstances, no need to post an answer. I only tried clarifying what was obvious. I do not care too much about notoriety... I had a personal target of 2000 points and I got it, already.

Comment: @FaneDuru ,"with sheet" "end with"  
you mean 2 lines like that, yes and before that I used the code for multi sheets and I plan to use it for multi sheets too. But thanks for your help

Comment: This is why I said it **makes sense**. Welcome!

Comment: @FaneDuru , okay